# NSOutlineView and NSTreeController example

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-bindings, nsoutlineview, nstreecontroller

Please send me some links on how to use [NSOutlineView](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSOutlineView_Class/index.html) with [NSTreeController](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSTreeController_Class/) bindings without using core data.

Answer (score 9):

In addition to the documentation, Apple's sample [SourceView project](http://developer.apple.com/samplecode/SourceView/index.html) should help you better understand things:

> "SourceView" is a Cocoa application that demonstrates how to use NSOutlineView driven by NSTreeController and various other Cocoa classes to produce a Finder-like left column source view. Among the key features used to imitate this commonly used view are the use of NSTableViewSelectionHighlightStyleSourceList, NSViewController, NSCollectionView, and WebView.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a useful blog-post, which I wrote, which may prove to be useful: [The simplest NSTreeController example](http://daemonconstruction.blogspot.in/2012/03/simplest-nstreecontroller-example.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can find a simple example of a NSOutlineView datasource in my response to [NSOutlineView example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6664898/nsoutlineview-example/9387255#9387255)